# ASP.net Back button from logout goes to previous page despite caching turned off

Tags: asp.net

I have an application where when I log out and press back button of browser, I am redirected to cached version of page showing only the static data(the data which comes dynamically is not shown).

Now, I have all the code pertaining to disabling the caching in place. I have used the following methods in my code

1. **Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

   Response.Buffer = true;

   Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

   Response.Expires = 0;

   Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";**
2. **javascript: window.history.forward(1);**
3. **Page.Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");**
4. I tried disabling the output cache setting in IIS(Ver 7.5) from the Inetmgr but no use.

In fact, I have tried all the steps I could find online in my code

**Intresting thing is:**All the above solution work fine on my dev machine. They also work fine when I browse them from Inetmgr(url syaing localhost://xyz) of my prod server. **BUT** None of these work when I actually use the website.

I use a normal anchor tag for logout and no server control on my page.

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

Try preventing back button on the particular page using javascript..

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
        function preventBack() { window.history.forward(); }
        setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
        window.onunload = function () { null };
</script>
```

Comment: Please read the question again. I have already tried it out. The answer you suggested works fine on my dev environment but not when I used it on deployed code. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: Its working fine for me both on localhost and on deployed website..So I posted the answer,Regards..